keytheorems - Numbering format: remove number of parent subsections
I would like to adapt the following code to obtain the output indicated after. How can I achieve that?
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{keytheorems}

\newkeytheorem{mytest}[
    name   = My test,
    within = subsection
]

\begin{document}

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}

\begin{mytest}
   Bla, bla, bla, ...
\end{mytest}

\begin{mytest}
   Bla, bla, bla, ...
\end{mytest}

\end{document}

Output expected without the number of the subsection.
My test 1. Bla, bla, bla, ... 

My test 2. Bla, bla, bla, ...


The beloved French style in which you have a dozen of Theorem 1 and you need to specify a cross reference like in “Theorem 1 in section 23”. And maybe in some section there is a Lemma 4 that you cannot tell whether it's before or after Theorem 2. I have a book like this, where cross refences are a nightmare; of course the page headings bear no useful information. Number your statements all together and just by (chapter.)section. Your readers will be grateful.

I use the same numbers for theorems, lemmas and the like. I've suffered so much reading Dieudonné's excellent books, so I don't want to become a torturer. :) But here the numbering is for technical documentation without cross-referencing, and that makes sense. My problem is mainly with the number.

In the English version of his Fundaments of Mathematical Analysis, Dieudonné switched to a consistent numbering, chapter.section.statement(.step)

Assuming your expected output is that the mytest counter resets after every subsection, you can do \renewcommand{\themytest}{\arabic{mytest}}. The default is \thesubsection .\arabic {mytest} which you can see with \show\themytest.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{keytheorems}

\newkeytheorem{mytest}[
    name   = My test,
    within = subsection
]
\renewcommand{\themytest}{\arabic{mytest}}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}

\begin{mytest}
   Bla, bla, bla, ...
\end{mytest}

\begin{mytest}
   Bla, bla, bla, ...
\end{mytest}

\subsection{Another Subsection}

\begin{mytest}
   Bla, bla, bla, ...
\end{mytest}

\begin{mytest}
   Bla, bla, bla, ...
\end{mytest}
\end{document}



I was expected a keytheorems solution. But I should at least try a standard solution first.

@projetmbc This would be easy to implement, something like thecounter=\arabic{mytest}, but it would do exactly what I've done above. And for the reasons expressed in egreg's comment, I'm not sure I want to encourage this
